# Matching partial ids in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using **BeautifulSoup**. I have to find any reference to the `<div>` tags with id like: `post-#`.

For example:

```html
<div id="post-45">...</div>
<div id="post-334">...</div>
```

I have tried:

```
html = '<div id="post-45">...</div> <div id="post-334">...</div>'
soupHandler = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soupHandler.findAll('div', id='post-*')
```

How can I filter this?

Comment: What version of BeautifulSoup are you using?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can pass a function to [findAll](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs%29):

```
>>> print soupHandler.findAll('div', id=lambda x: x and x.startswith('post-'))
[<div id="post-45">...</div>, <div id="post-334">...</div>]
```

Or a regular expression:

```
>>> print soupHandler.findAll('div', id=re.compile('^post-'))
[<div id="post-45">...</div>, <div id="post-334">...</div>]
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Comment: I've fixed the `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 7):

Since he is asking to match "post-#somenumber#", it's better to precise with

```
import re
[...]
soupHandler.findAll('div', id=re.compile("^post-\d+"))
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = '<div id="post-45">...</div> <div id="post-334">...</div>'
soupHandler = BeautifulSoup(html)

for match in soupHandler.find_all('div', id=re.compile("post-")):
    print match.get('id')

>>> 
post-45
post-334
```

Answer (score 1):

```
soupHandler.findAll('div', id=re.compile("^post-$"))
```

looks right to me.

Comment: Why did you put the `$`? I don't think that will work as the OP intends.