# How to scrape text from paragraphs with different id name?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am trying to scrape text from paragraphs with different id names. The text looks as follows:

```
<p id="comFull1" class="comment" style="display:none"><strong>Comment:
</strong><br>I realized how much Abilify has been helping me when I recently 
tried to taper off of it. I am on the bipolar spectrum, with mainly 
depression and some OCD symptoms. My obsessive, intrusive thoughts came 
racing back when I decreased the medication. I also got much more tired and 
had insomnia with the decrease. am not happy with side effects of 15 lb 
weight gain, increased cholesterol and a flat effect on my emotions. I am 
actually wondering if an increase from the 7 mg would help even more...for 
now I&#39;m living with the side effects.<br><a 
onclick="toggle('comTrunc1'); toggle('comFull1');return false;" 
href="#">Hide Full Comment</a></p>

<p id="comFull2" class="comment" style="display:none"><strong>Comment:
</strong><br>It&#39;s worked Very well for me. I&#39;m sleeping I&#39;m 
eating I&#39;m going Out in the public. Overall I&#39;m very 
satisfied.However I haven&#39;t heard anybody mention this but my feet are 
very puffy and swollen is this a side effect does anyone know?<br><a 
onclick="toggle('comTrunc2'); toggle('comFull2');return false;" 
href="#">Hide Full Comment</a></p>

......
```

I am able to scrap text only from a particular id but not with all id at a time. Can anyone help on this issue to scrap text from all ids. The code looks like this

```
>>> from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> url = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
>>> req = Request(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
>>> webpage = urlopen(req).read()
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")
>>> required2 = soup.find("p", {"id": "comFull1"}).text
>>> required2
"Comment:I realized how much Abilify has been helping me when I recently 
tried to taper off of it. I am on the bipolar spectrum, with mainly 
depression and some OCD symptoms. My obsessive, intrusive thoughts came 
racing back when I decreased the medication. I also got much more tired and 
had insomnia with the decrease. am not happy with side effects of 15 lb 
weight gain, increased cholesterol and a flat effect on my emotions. I am 
actually wondering if an increase from the 7 mg would help even more...for 
now I'm living with the side effects.Hide Full Comment"
```

Comment: Just don't mention the id: `soup.findAll("p")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. If all the ID numbers containing paragraphs are suffixed `1,2,3 e.t.c` to it, as in `comFull1,comFull2,comFull3` then the below selector should handle it.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
for item in soup.select("[id^='comFull']"):
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having as understood by me is to scrape the text of all paragraphs in a webpage or **<\p>** tags.

The function you are looking for is -

```
soup.find_all('p')
```

A more comprehensive example is shown in the following docs -

*https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use xpath you can use

```
response.xpath("//p[contains(@id,'comFull')]/text()").extract()
```

But since you are using beautiful soup you can pass a function or regular expression to `find_all` method as mentioned here.
[Matching id's in BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830530/matching-ids-in-beautifulsoup)

```
soup.find_all('p', id=re.compile('^comFull-'))
```