# Beautiful Soup Find Tags based on partial attribute value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to identify tags in an html document based on part of the attribute value.

For example, if I have a Beautifulsoup object:

```
import bs4 as BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http:/My_Page")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
```

I want `tr` tags with `id` attribute whose values are formatted like this: "news_4343_23255_xxx".  I'm interested in any `tr` tag as long as it has "news" as the first 4 characters of the `id` attribute value.

I know I can search as follows:

```
trs = soup.find_all("tr",attrs={"id":True})
```

which gives me all `tr` tages with an `id` attribute.

How do I seach based on a substring?

Answer (score 9):

Use **regex** to get `tr` with `id` starting with `"news"`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,  "html.parser")
for i in soup.find_all("tr", {'id': re.compile(r'^news')}):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`trs = soup.find_all("tr", id=lambda x: x and x.startswith('news_')`

referenced here: [Matching id's in BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830530/matching-ids-in-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex for that.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


r = requests.get("example")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
regex = re.compile('news')
news = soup.find_all("td", {"class" : regex})
print news
```

Comment: This is the same as [Rakesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532312/rakesh)'s solution. Please don't post the same solution if it doesn't add anything new to the question.

Comment: @return the previous answer is only two minutes younger than this one.  It's possible that they typed with some care, as they should, and that it took longer than two minutes to compose this answer (their first).  Please don't post comments without considering whether they are truly necessary, and perhaps be more kind when you do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another case here, this doesn't solve the exact question asked above but it can help someone if he/she comes here by seeing just the title:

#### Use regex

**Case :** Suppose I have list of `div`(s) with `class` as follows:

```
<div class='abcd bcde cdef efgh'>some content</div>
<div class='mnop bcde cdef efgh'>some content</div>
<div class='abcd pqrs cdef efgh'>some content</div>
<div class='hijk wxyz cdef efgh'>some content</div>
```

As observable, the ***class value strings*** of above `div`(s) ends with `cdef efgh`; to extract all these in a single list:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re # library for regex in python
soup = BeautifulSoup(<your_html_response>, <parser_you_want_to_use>)
elements = soup.find_all('div', {'class': re.compile(r'cdef efgh$')})
```

Want to know what is:

- 'r' before the string means : [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals)
- '$' means that 'cdef efgh' must be end of strings

> **Note**: This was just one case. You can make almost any case with regex. Learn more and experiment with regex at https://regex101.com/