# Searching specific divs with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm looking to scrape a specific web page for the following tag:

```
<div about="/our-people/john-smith" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document" class="ds-2col-stacked node node--contact view-mode-contact_display_block  node--contact-display-block node--contact--contact-display-block clearfix">
```

There's a bunch of instaces like that on the page, so I'm looking for the name at the end of this part of the tag:

```
<div about="/our-people/john-smith"
```

to eventually be turned into a list of all times that that occurs on the page for each person, as such:

```
('John Smith','Jane Do', 'Regis Kelly')
```

At the moment I have this, but this doesn't find me all cases that have /our-people/

```
driver.get(url)
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
print(soup.find('div', {'about':'/our-people/john-smith'}))
```

How would I achieve this? 
Thanks

Comment: Please refer [#50630476](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50630160/beautiful-soup-find-tags-based-on-partial-attribute-value/50630476)

Comment: @JasonYang what is soup = BeautifulSoup(html,  "html.parser"). I'm getting NameError: name 'html' is not defined

Comment: html is your content in your code

Comment: In what format? I dont understand how could I put it in a variable if I can't even find what I'm trying to look for

Comment: html is the content of web html, like '<!DOCTYPE html> <html class="html__responsive"> <head> ....'

Comment: driver.get(url)
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

Comment: Yep ok gotcha. Thanks