# Using Python Beautiful Soup is there way for me to search for the first few characters of a html id?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I was wondering if there a way for me to search for the first few characters of an id. Eg using the find(id=''), if an item id was 'priceblock_ourprice' could I search just for items with the id starting with 'priceblock'?

I have searched for ways to do this but my searches have been fruitful.
and nothing i have tried has worked. Maybe something like this would work:

```
soup.find(id[0:9]="priceblock")
```

of course this didn't work but I was hoping someone has a fix, thanks in advance <3

Comment: Check answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830530/matching-partial-ids-in-beautifulsoup

Comment: Just as reminder - you can always solve such kind of simple tasks in plain Python. BeautifulSoup solves for you all HTML-related problems, next your can simply iterate across all IDs with regular expressions, custom functions and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `select_one` with css selector, `[id^='priceblock']` means **id** starts with **priceblock**:

```
soup.select_one("[id^='priceblock']")
```