# How to search for part of id while web scraping?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning python web scraping and I am testing it and so far its giving me what I need but one record.

Upon checking the id I am testing scraping on is appended by some characters before. e.g.:

```
 id="List_1__firstName"
```

So I want to get records using part of the id more like `%%_firstName`.

```
_firstName
```

How do I go about this? This is my current code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://****.co**/'
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
Name = soup.find(id='List_l0_l00_firstName').get_text()
print(Name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following question helps you.

[Matching partial ids in BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830530/matching-partial-ids-in-beautifulsoup)

You can use `find_all`.

```py
import re
soup.find_all(id=re.compile('_firstName$'))
```

### Additional comment

Here is my local testing script and result which mentioned in below comment.

> That's strange... Actually, I've tried in my local to test it and worked. I've added my console output, python script, and html file in my answer above just now.

#### output

```
$ ls 
index.html  main.py

$ python3 main.py
foo
bar
baz
```

#### python script (main.py)

```py
import bs4
import re

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('index.html'), 'html.parser')
elements = soup.find_all(id=re.compile('_firstName$'))

for el in elements:
  print(el.get_text())
```

#### html file (index.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="List_1__firstName">foo</div>
  <div id="List_2__firstName">bar</div>
  <div id="List_3__firstName">baz</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### my environment

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.6

$ pip show beautifulsoup4
Name: beautifulsoup4
Version: 4.9.3
Summary: Screen-scraping library
Home-page: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/
Author: Leonard Richardson
Author-email: leonardr@segfault.org
License: MIT
Location: /Users/ntb/envs/bs/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: soupsieve
Required-by:
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I ended up using 

```
Name = soup.findAll('span', id=re.compile('_firstName'))
```

Its giving me all the span tags with data, I am interested in getting only the data for that span or div.

Initially with get_text(), I could get only a single record.

Comment: I think you can iterate the result and call `get_text()` for each element.

Comment: Its giving me this error attributeError: 're.Pattern' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: That's strange...
Actually, I've tried in my local to test it and worked.

I've added my console output, python script, and html file in my answer above just now.